# Timestamps in Git

Tags: git, merge, timestamp

**Questions**

1. When I commit a revision to a branch is their a "commit timestamp" recorded and if so is it ever used and for what? It seems to me like the commit chains/trees would be all you need.
2. If there is a "commit timestamps" who records it, the client (committee) or server (main repository)?
3. When I merge two branches, what is taken into consideration when doing the merge? Basically what rules does the merge play by? Does it write the files with less commits under it? Does it use timestamps to determine which is newer?

Thanks in advance, looking for answers or good resources.

Comment: Please ask one question per post. That is how the Q/A format of Stack Overflow is designed to work.

Comment: All the questions are tightly related. I figured they'd be better together.

Comment: @PatrickLorio: The third actually has nothing to do with the first two, and the first and second are only somewhat related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you will see the time the commit was made when you look at the log.  Example:

   ```
   $ git log -1
   commit 4f0ba140d3a9709825c4d6b77ca5b69d09825c41
   Author: Somebody <someone@somewhere>
   Date:   Tue Jan 24 16:36:55 2012 -0800

       Commit message goes here
   ```
2. Git is distributed, there are no clients or servers.
3. It depends on how you want the merge to work.  [The documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-merge) will describe all of the possible options for you.  The basic merge case just takes all of the commits since the common ancestor.

Comment: 2 in that case how are the timestamps synced or are they?

Comment: If you push your commits to another repository, or if someone else pulls them, the timestamps will go along.

Comment: Lets say Bob makes a commit on branch A and his local clock is 5 hours ahead and Jill makes a commit on branch B right after Bob's commit. On merge will Bob's commit override Jill's?

Comment: You'll get both.  If there's a conflict, you'll need to resolve it.  Does the ordering of the commits really matter?  That's kind of what git is all about - you could reorder them however you like if you don't like what the merge did.

Comment: @PatrickLorio: *Everything* is about commits. A commit represents a snapshot of the contents of the repository. It records the time only for your benefit, so you can see when it was made; it has no bearing on the content. A merge is a commit with two parents, and the resulting snapshot should be the combination of the changes made since a common ancestor up to each of those two commits. Nothing can ever override anything; if the two sides disagree, that's a conflict you have to deal with. Recommended reading: http://tom.preston-werner.com/2009/05/19/the-git-parable.html

Comment: @PatrickLorio: And the timestamp is part of the commit, so it's recorded when the commit is made, in the repository you make it in. After that, the commit may be transferred to another repository if you wish; the entire commit is copied intact, timestamp, message, contents and all.

Comment: The timestamp is part of the commit, as mentioned, which means that it is used when calculating the SHA-1 hash of that commit. Further, this means that if you have the SHA-1 hash for the head of a branch, then the timestamp (and all the rest of the data) for EVERY parent of that ref are used to compute it, making the hash unique not just to that commit but to the entire history.