# Does git merge take into account timestamps on merged files?

Tags: git

When merging two files, does git take into account which file is newer and which one is older? If yes, what happens with timezones, what if one user has an older file but their timezone makes it look newer?

Comment: @castis so can the timezone delta be a problem with commit timestamps?

Comment: As I say that I realize I am wrong. Timestamps are probably not even involved in the merge process. Every commit is based on an earlier commit so the only thing that matters is that the commits existed beforehand. [Check out this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105465/timestamps-in-git)

Answer (score 5):

> so can the timezone delta be a problem with commit timestamps

No: [only the graph of commit matters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6191836/6309), whatever their associated date is.
A commit can in theory have a parent commit created *after* said commit (instead of before): the date is an arbitrary metadata you associate to a commit when you create it, like the author string. (see for instance the [`GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITER_DATE` environment variables](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_committing))

The recent (Q2 2018) [commit-graph feature from Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2018/06/25/supercharging-the-git-commit-graph/) does not depend on dates at all, for instance. (see [Git Commit Graph Design Notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c05048d43925ab8edcb36663752c2b4541911231/Documentation/technical/commit-graph.txt))

See more with "[“Chronological” ordering: time is an illusion; log time, doubly so](https://redfin.engineering/visualize-merge-history-with-git-log-graph-first-parent-and-no-merges-c6a9b5ff109c#2953)".